# Java: how to get an object to refer to the object it was instantiated in

Tags: java, object

I am still quite inexperienced with using Java, and would like to solve this stumbling block:

I have created two classes to be used in a rigid body dynamics simulation, called:

`RigidBody`
`RigidBodyElement`

The plan is to create a `RigidBody` object. This object will be comprised of many little `RigidBodyElement` objects. So, inside `RigidBody`, there will be a single array of type `RigidBodyElements` to contain all of the rigid body elements.

As for `RigidBodyElement`, there will be a field variable containing the coordinates of the element relative to a fixed point on the `RigidBody` object. This variable will be called `relativeCoordinates`.

That much is fine. The problem arises when we want to find the absolute coordinates of each element, `absoluteCoordinates`. To find that, we would need to add the rotated `relativeCoordinates` of `RigidBodyElement` to the coordinates of the overall rigid body, `RigidBody`. i.e. writing a function in `RigidBodyElement`, such that when an instance of `RigidBodyElements` calls this function, it will get some of the information from the instance of the class `RigidBody` in which this element is instantiated.

I currently have no idea how to define a function for an object to refer to another object that has instantiated the first object.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `this` keyword.

So you should have a constructor like this:

```
RigidBodyElement(RigidBody body)
{
    ....
}
```

And instantiate it like this in an instance method of RigidBody:

```
new RigidBodyElement(this);
```

Answer (score 3):

another approach is that you could make RigidBodyElement an Inner class.

```
public class RigidBody{

  private double x, y;
  private List<RigidBodyElement> elements = new ArrayList<>();

  public RigidBody(){
    elements.add(new RigidBodyElement(50,20));
  }

  public class RigidBodyElement(){
    private double x, y;
    public RigidBodyElement(double x, double y){
      this.x=x;
      this.y=y;
    }

    public double getAbsoluteX(){
      //RigidBody.this references the RigidBody which created this element
      return RigidBody.this.x + this.x;
    }
  }
}
```